# Tunneling to access a remote server: channel 2: open failed:

Tags: networking, ssh, unix, port-forwarding, tunnel

I've tried looking at similar articles here but they haven't helped.

I am using a tunnel to forward traffic to port 8080 of a server using the following command:

ssh user@ -L 8080:SERVER:8080 -N

It works perfectly. There is another server on this host listening to port 85. When I do the following:

ssh -v user@ -L 86:10.32.226.116:85 -N

And go to localhost:86 I get the following:

```
Authenticated to SERVER ([SERVER]:22).
debug1: Local connections to localhost:86 forwarded to remote address SERVER:85
debug1: Local forwarding listening on ::1 port 86.
debug1: channel 0: new [port listener]
debug1: Local forwarding listening on 127.0.0.1 port 86.
debug1: channel 1: new [port listener]
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: Connection to port 86 forwarding to SERVER port 85 requested.
debug1: channel 2: new [direct-tcpip]
channel 2: open failed: connect failed: Connection refused
debug1: channel 2: free: direct-tcpip: listening port 86 for SERVER port 85, connect from 127.0.0.1 port 58045, nchannels 3
```

Apologies for the formatting, this is a bit new to me.

Can someone help with this? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Major difference: port 8080 is not privileged, port 85/86 (being smaller than 1024) is. From the ssh man page

> Only the superuser can forward privileged ports